# Is there a way to know that nodeunit has finished all tests?

Tags: node.js, firebase, nodeunit

I need to run some code after `nodeunit` successfully passed all tests. 
I'm testing some `Firebase` wrappers and `Firebase` reference blocks exiting nodeunit after all test are run.

I am looking for some hook or callback to run after all unit tests are passed. So I can terminate `Firebase` process in order `nodeunit` to be able to exit.

Comment: The answer to your question is to use setup and teardown. If you declare these at the root level, they run for each test, so you can determine how many tests ran and when they are completed. However, this is an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Your real question is why do your test units hang and how do you stop them from doing so? It would help to be a bit more specific here and provide something users can reproduce.

Comment: You actually gave me good answer, that can solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't found a right way to do it.

There is my *temporary* solution:

```
//Put a *LAST* test to clear all if needed:
exports.last_test = function(test){
    //do_clear_all_things_if_needed();
    setTimeout(process.exit, 500); // exit in 500 milli-seconds    
    test.done(); 
}
```

In my case, this is used to make sure DB connection or some network connect get killed any way. The reason it works is because **nodeunit** run tests in series.

It's not the best, even not the good way, just to let the test **exit**.

For **nodeunit** 0.9.0

Answer (score 2):

For a recent project, we counted the tests by iterating `exports`, then called `tearDown` to count the completions. After the last test exits, we called process.exit().

[See the spec](https://github.com/oalami/trends/blob/master/spec/spec.api_methods.js) for full details. Note that this went at the end of the file (after all the tests were added onto exports)

```
(function(exports) {
  // firebase is holding open a socket connection
  // this just ends the process to terminate it
  var total = 0, expectCount = countTests(exports);
  exports.tearDown = function(done) {
    if( ++total === expectCount ) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        process.exit();
      }, 500);
    }
    done();
  };

  function countTests(exports) {
    var count = 0;
    for(var key in exports) {
      if( key.match(/^test/) ) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
})(exports);
```

Comment: This not work in my case. The **exports.tearDown** got run each test.

Comment: Yes, it is called each time, which is why we keep a count and only run the teardown after the final test.

Answer (score 0):

As per nodeunit docs I can't seem to find a way to provide a callback after all tests have ran.

I suggest that you use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) so you can create a test workflow with tasks, for example:

1. Install the command line tool: `npm install -g grunt-cli`
2. Install grunt to your project `npm install grunt --save-dev`
3. Install the nodeunit grunt plugin: `npm install grunt-contrib-nodeunit --save-dev`
4. Create a Gruntfile.js like the following:

   ```
   module.exports = function(grunt) {

       grunt.initConfig({
           nodeunit : {
               all : ['tests/*.js'] //point to where your tests are
           }
       });

       grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-nodeunit');

       grunt.registerTask('test', [
           'nodeunit'
       ]);
   };
   ```
5. Create your custom task that will be run after the tests by changing your grunt file to the following:

   ```
   module.exports = function(grunt) {

       grunt.initConfig({
           nodeunit : {
               all : ['tests/*.js'] //point to where your tests are
           }
       });

       grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-nodeunit');

       //this is just an example you can do whatever you want
       grunt.registerTask('generate-build-json', 'Generates a build.json file containing date and time info of the build', function() {
           fs.writeFileSync('build.json', JSON.stringify({
               platform: os.platform(),
               arch: os.arch(),
               timestamp: new Date().toISOString()
           }, null, 4));

           grunt.log.writeln('File build.json created.');
       });

       grunt.registerTask('test', [
           'nodeunit',
           'generate-build-json'
       ]);
   };
   ```
6. Run your test tasks with `grunt test`

Comment: well my problem is related to Firebase reference which is still running after all tests are done and prevents them to finish. Thus I need to run some housekeeping right after it. I don't thing grunt would help here.

Comment: Humm... not sure what Firebase is but if your tests are not finishing then IMO I think that you should rephrase your question.

Comment: tests are finishing, all passing, the process is not exiting because of Firebase connection. What I wanted is to know if there is a hook where I could run a code after all tests are passed and before nodeunit exits. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I came across another solution how to deal with this solution. I have to say the all answers here are correct. However when inspecting grunt I found out that Grunt is running nodeunit tests via reporter and the reporter offers a callback option when all tests are finished. It could be done something like this:

in folder

```
test_scripts/
   some_test.js
```

test.js can contain something like this:

```
//loads default reporter, but any other can be used
var reporter = require('nodeunit').reporters.default;
// safer exit, but process.exit(0) will do the same in most cases
var exit = require('exit');

reporter.run(['test/basic.js'], null, function(){
    console.log(' now the tests are finished');
    exit(0);
});
```

the script can be added to let's say `package.json` in script object

```
  "scripts": {
    "nodeunit": "node scripts/some_test.js",
  },
```

now it can be done as

```
npm run nodeunit
```

the tests in some_tests.js can be chained or it can be run one by one using npm